# How to customise django inline admin form's delete function

Tags: python, django

How do I customise **Django's** inline admin form's *delete action*. My `admin.py` setup is below:

```
#admin.py
class ChildModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ChildModel
    can_delete = True

#admin.py
@admin.register(ParentModel)
class ParentModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ChildModelInline,]
```

The `ChildModel` is related to the `ParentModel` by a `models.ForeignKey` field. I would like to be able to select multiple child objects on the `ParentModel's Inline Form` to be removed, but not delete the child object from the database, just remove the ForeignKey relationship in the child obj.

Comment: First of all `can_delete` is true by default, you can remove that. As for deleting child reference, you need to override the delete method for `ChildModel` and set related `ParentModelAdmin` to None and don't delete the child.

Answer (score 2):

You should define a custom Formset and override the delete behaviour. Here's the code:

```
class ChildFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def delete_existing(self, obj, commit=True):
        obj.parent = None
        if commit:
            obj.save()


class ChildModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ChildModel
    formset = ChildFormSet


@admin.register(ParentModel)
class ParentModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ChildModelInline,]
```

Answer (score 0):

What all you can do is first define a custom action for the respective model and in that action just put the `models.ForeignKey` field to `null`.So it will remove the child parent relation between the objects but it won't delete the object from the database.

Answer (score 0):

It can be controlled from the `on_delete` attribute of model property. Lookinto the below line:

```
option = models.ForeignKey(ServiceOption, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='additional')
```